# Xcode Bring TableView To Front

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview, storyboard

Im having trouble finding an answer to this.
I have a TableView in a plain View Controller.
When I add a control or another view controller, the TableView vanishes (to the back I assume) and I can't bring it back to the front (the option is greyed out in storyboard editor).

Please can someone tell me what Im doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Can you select the TableView on the left side in Document Outline? My Xcode is tripping for a week now, when I add a control or resize something my TableViews resize to 0 by 0 on top left side. I can resize them back in the Size Inspector.

Comment: If it still had the normal size you can select the TableView and drag it to the bottom of the View in the Document Outline like in this [picture](http://codewithchris.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/img/toggle_storyboard_document_outline.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

Using the View Controller tree in the Storyboard editor, you can re-arrange views and controls in the list by dragging them up and down. The bottom of the list is equivalent to the top of the view stack.

[image]

Comment: Hi and thanks. It doesn't seem to work though. I can't move the order (only select). The TableView only vanishes to the back when I try to resize another view. PS - Im using the latest version of Xcode.

Comment: @LB79 Can you upload an image somewhere of what your view hierarchy looks like? (I can then edit it into your post since you don't have enough reputation yet).

Comment: Thanks for the offer - I don't have anywhere to upload it to though. This reputation thing can be a bit annoying for newbies like me but I can understand the reason. I found a workaround which I have posted.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that the issue can be resolved by adding constraints before adding another control/view. Another developer has reported the issue to Apple as a bug.